# UnityとPUN2を使用してリモートプレイヤーの視点を2Dウィンドウで表示する方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

皆さん、こんにちは。UnityとPhoton Unity Networking 2 (PUN2)を使用し、リモートプレイヤーの視界をリアルタイムで2Dウィンドウに表示するVRシステムを開発中です。リモートプレイヤーの視界をキャプチャし、それをローカルプレイヤーのUIに小窓として表示する機能を実装しようとしています。

私の主な疑問点は以下の通りです：

1.RenderTextureを使用してキャプチャしたリモートプレイヤーの視界を効率的にネットワーク経由で他のプレイヤーに送信する最適な方法は何でしょうか？
受信したデータをローカルプレイヤーのUI上で2Dウィンドウとしてどのように表示すればよいでしょうか？
2.添付画像は、UnityのResourcesフォルダー直下にある「Network Player」の階層を示しています。私はこの階層にある白いパネルに他プレイヤーの視界をレンダリングしたいと考えています。この機能の実装に関するアドバイスや参考になるリソースを提供していただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]